# Structs in C Programming

Tags: c, struct

I'm trying to read a files contents and store them in to a struct for some reason I keep getting segmentation fault. Help me please, I don't understand valgrind much either.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
    char text[401];
} journal;

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    int  i, numberEntries;
    FILE* fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    fscanf(fp,"%d", &numberEntries); /* reads value on first line of file for number of entries */
    printf("%d", numberEntries); /* check that it worked */
    journal *entryArray ;
    entryArray = (journal*)malloc(sizeof(journal));

    if(fp == NULL){
        perror("Error opening file");
    } else {

        for(i=0; i<4; i++){
            fscanf(fp,"%d/%d/%d", entryArray[i].day, entryArray[i].month, entryArray[i].year);
            fgets(entryArray[i].text, 400, fp);
            printf("%s", entryArray[i].text);
        }
    } 
    for(i=0; i<4; i++){
        printf("%d %d %d", entryArray[i].day, entryArray[i].month, entryArray[i].year);
        printf("%s", entryArray[i].text);
    }
    free(entryArray);
    return 0;
}
```

Updated code: still gives segmentation fault.

```
typedef struct {
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
    char text[401];
} journal;

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    int  i, numberEntries;
    FILE* fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if(fp == NULL){
        perror("Error opening file");
    } else {
        fscanf(fp,"%d", &numberEntries); /* reads value on first line of file for number of entries */
        printf("%d", numberEntries); /* check that it worked */
        journal *entryArray ;
        entryArray = (journal*)malloc(numberEntries*sizeof(journal));
        for(i=0; i<4; i++){
            fscanf(fp,"%d/%d/%d", &entryArray[i].day, &entryArray[i].month, &entryArray[i].year);
            fgets(entryArray[i].text, 400, fp);
            printf("%s", entryArray[i].text);
        }
        for(i=0; i<4; i++){
            printf("%d/%d/%d", entryArray[i].day, entryArray[i].month, entryArray[i].year);
            printf("%s", entryArray[i].text);
        }
        free(entryArray);
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Input file

```
4
12/04/2010
Interview went well I think, though was told to wear shoes.
18/04/2010
Doc advised me to concentrate on something... I forget.
03/05/2010
Was asked today if I was an art exhibit.
19/05/2010
Apparently mudcakes not made of mud, or angry wasps.
```

Comment: Use GDB to get segfault offset in your code. segfault can occure anywhere depending on situation. so it would be difficult to help you in this way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are at least three reasons that might (and will) cause segmentation fault in your program

- Firstly, you have a check in your program that verifies whether the file was opened successfully. Yet, you are trying to read data from the file *before* that check

  ```
  fscanf(fp,"%d", &numberEntries);
  ```

  If the file was not opened successfully, `fopen` returns null pointer. Trying to read anything through a null file pointer results in undefined behavior, which might easily manifest itself as a segmentation fault.
- Secondly, your `entryArray` is always allocated with only one element in it. Yet you are trying to access 4 elements. That can (and will) easily lead to segmentation fault as well.

  BTW, what was the point if reading `numberEntries` from the file and then completely ignore that value?
- Thirdly, `fscanf` with `%d` format requires a *pointer* to `int` as the corresponding variadic argument. You have supplied `int`s instead

  ```
  fscanf(fp,"%d/%d/%d", entryArray[i].day, entryArray[i].month, entryArray[i].year);
  ```

  This will also cause undefined behavior typically accompanied with a segmentation fault. Judging by your first `fscanf` you knew how to use `%d` with `fscanf`. Did you forget about it by the second `fscanf`?

If the file was opened successfully then there's is 99% chance that it is the third problem that causes the segmentation fault in your code. This problem reveals itself before the second problem.

---

Finally, the format of your input data does not match the format that you hardcoded into your program. Since you are using `fgets` immediately after `fscanf`, the `text` data must reside on the same line as the `day/month/year` data. Meanwhile, in your input file the `text` data resides on a separate line. This will definitely derail your reading code.

You have to skip over the rest of the line and the newline character after reading date and before doing `fgets`. One way to do it is to perform a "fake" `fgets` before doing the actual `fgets`

```
for(i=0; i<4; i++){
  fscanf(fp,"%d/%d/%d", &entryArray[i].day, &entryArray[i].month, &entryArray[i].year);
  fgets(entryArray[i].text, 400, fp); // <- fake `fgets`
  fgets(entryArray[i].text, 400, fp);
}
```

Alternatively, you can add a trailing space character into `fscanf` format to force `fscanf` to consume all trailing whitespace

```
for(i=0; i<4; i++){
  fscanf(fp,"%d/%d/%d ", &entryArray[i].day, &entryArray[i].month, &entryArray[i].year);
  fgets(entryArray[i].text, 400, fp);
}
```

Or you can use a more elaborate `fscanf` format to ask it to consume and ignore everything before the newline character and then the newline character itself

```
for (i = 0; i<4; i++){
  fscanf(fp, "%d/%d/%d%*[^\n]\n", &entryArray[i].day, &entryArray[i].month, &entryArray[i].year);
  fgets(entryArray[i].text, 400, fp);
}
```

These are not the best ways to do it, but they will work as long as your input file sticks to the hard format.

Comment: Hey I've updated the code based on your points but for some reason it shows the lower for loop entryArray as undeclared in the terminal, do you know why this could be happening? thanks.

Comment: @IamTrent:  A variable declared in a block `{ ... }` only exists to the end of that block. It does not exist outside of that block. You cannot access your `entryArray` outside of that `else { ... }` block. That's how it should be. Since you put almost everything into that `else` branch, just put the rest of the code in there as well.

Comment: Ok I updated the code and still get segfaults, any other ideas? thanks.

Comment: @IamTrent: Well, I tried to run your latest version and it runs perfectly fine for me. Of course, I had to create a fake the input file based on the format that I could "reverse engineer" from your code. I don't have your input data. It is possible that the format of your actual file does not match what you wrote in the code. Post your input file (or a portion of it, if it is too big) in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You allocate one journal `entryArray = (journal*)malloc(sizeof(journal));`, but then you treat it as an array `fgets(entryArray[i].text, 400, fp);`

That's not gonna work...